# how to get raw file from a web page showing source file?

Tags: git, wget, download

For example, in this page :
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/boot/dts/arm/fvp-base-revc.dts
I want to download the .dts file. But if I just do

```
wget https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/boot/dts/arm/fvp-base-revc.dts
```

it's not .dts file but a html-like file.
How can I download the displayed source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, [Elixir](https://github.com/bootlin/elixir) doesn’t provide a way to download the raw file it presents through its web interface. Instead, you should download the file you’re interested in from a git repository, *e.g.*

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/arch/arm64/boot/dts/arm/fvp-base-revc.dts
```

*I.e.* replace `https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/` with `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/` (both of these track the tip of Linus Torvalds’ tree).